# How to retrieve UserID from Task Assignments?

Tags: json, powershell, api

I work with API Graph in PowerShell to get Planner tasks. I retrieve the task in my plan but i can't get the user id who the task is assigned.

How can I parse this JSON, in PowerShell for get the value : "8dfb0c3c-5c2b-47eb-924f-ab9365ca9d89"?

A very big thanks for your help.

```
{
    "8dfb0c3c-5c2b-47eb-924f-ab9365ca9d89":  {
          "@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
          "assignedDateTime":  "2018-06-12T09:32:27.9137819Z",
          "orderHint":  "",
          "assignedBy":  {
                "user":  "@{displayName=; id=rHcFhQEnpUm_DNWYU1mTYZYAB64F}"
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when getting object by conversion from JSON (ConvertFrom-JSON), you get PSCustomObject. To get the top level keys you can enumerate its members of NoteProperty type. See example below.

```
$jsonData = Get-Content -Path <FilePath> | ConvertFrom-Json
$topLevelKeys = $jsonData | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
foreach ($m_topLevelKey in $topLevelKeys) { <do something> }
```

Hope I got your question right